# Shell-script extract value pair with sed/awk?

Tags: awk, sed, string

Given a string like this:

```
NAME="bla" TYPE="test" SIZE="10"
```

I want to get the values for each pair into into separate shell-script vars.
So, for example, say we have three variables I want to load the values bla in the first variable, test in the second and 10 in the third.

```
name=bla
type=test
size=10
```

What I tried so far:

```
echo \"NAME=\"bla\" TYPE=\"test\" SIZE=\"10\"" | awk '{print Var, $1}'
```

But that would return the entire key-value pair, instead of just the value.
Is there a nice way to do this with sed or awk?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you [edit] your question to tell us **what** you're trying to do instead of **how** you're trying to do it then we can help you. For example tell us where this string of tag-value pairs came from (a file? output of a command? argument to a script? something else?) and what you want to do with the variables you create from it. Also - if you don't actually want the variable names converted to lower case then [edit] your example to fix that.

Comment: Your input string looks like valid shell code to me. Why don't you just `source` or `eval` it?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't necessarily recommend it but you could just do the following if you're completely in control of what your string contains and it doesn't contain any globbing chars, etc.:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str='NAME="bla" TYPE="test" SIZE="10"'
declare $str

echo "NAME=$NAME"
echo "TYPE=$TYPE"
echo "SIZE=$SIZE"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
NAME="bla"
TYPE="test"
SIZE="10"
```

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str='NAME="bla" TYPE="test" SIZE="10"'
declare ${str,,}

echo "name=$name"
echo "type=$type"
echo "size=$size"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
name="bla"
type="test"
size="10"
```

Comment: Is there any benefit in `declare $str` over simply `. <(echo "$str")`? Also, your second approach would change the values to lower case as well, not just the variable names. So if `str` contained `NAME="bLa"`, your `$name` would be `bla` instead.

Comment: @terdon For the first thing - declare doesn't create a temp file and IMHO is simpler than `. <(echo "$str")` but nbd either way. For the second thing - I know but not sure if it matters to the OPs data (maybe it's all lower case alpha-numeric as in their provided example), am hoping the OP will clarify what they actually are doing before posting a better answer if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution:

```bsh
$ string='NAME="bla" TYPE="test" SIZE="10"'
$ IFS=' ' read -a a <<< "$string"
for i in "${a[@]}"; do
  var="${i%%=*}"
  value="${i##*=}"
  declare "${var,,}"="${value//\"/}"
done
```

Then

```
$ echo $name
bla
$ echo $type
test
$ echo $size
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Although better answers are already there (`declare $str`), I'll leave some other options here.

With `source`:

```bsh
source <(echo 'NAME="bla" TYPE="test kkk" SIZE="10"')
```

With `eval`:

```
eval 'NAME="bla" TYPE="test kkk" SIZE="10"'
```

Both deal with parameter escaping and whitespaces (for example `SIZE="with a space"`).

Both are subject to parameter expansion, though: `SIZE="*"` or `SIZE="$(hostname)"` WILL be expanded/run.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but if you want to store the value in another variables, you can do as below:

```
echo "NAME="bla" TYPE="test" SIZE="10"" | tr ' ' '\n' | while read line
do
   #this will give you the value. save it in any variable you want.
   name=$(echo $line | awk -F= '{print $2}') 
done
```

once you get the value, use the if condition to store them in diff variable as per the value.

Comment: You have an extra `"` after `"10""`.

Comment: Thanks but that should not cause any isssue. I ran locally.

Comment: @RajnishKumarSoni Note that the strings `bla`, `test` and `10` are all unquoted in your code.  If any of those string contains spaces or shell globbing patterns (e.g. `*`), you may have issues.  This is due to you using double quotes to quote the double quoted strings.  It would be better to use single quotes around the string that `echo` outputs.  This is also related to the other user's comment on your answer.